# Django Integrity Error -- Multiple Foreign Keys to User

Tags: python, django

I am trying to design a basic CRM with an "owner" column and a "client" column. Because the clients can only have one owner they all have a one-to-one relationship to the User table. The "owner" column is a simple ForeignKey back to the User table. This is what the model looks like:

```
class CRM (models.Model):     
    client = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='client')     
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner')
```

However when I run the code to add more than one client to an owner Django complains: Integrity Error, column owner_id is not unique.

If I make owner unique then no owner could have more than one client. I am making additions using the Django Admin currently. How can this problem be solved? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share the snippet that shows how you're adding multiple clients with respect to this model? It will help

Comment: I think you should use ManyToManyField instead of ForeignKey

Comment: if *the clients can only have one owner*, then you should declare that in the `Client` model. I'm not sure what you plan to do with the CRM model. But it doesn't seem right. Declaring `ForeignKey` to `User` means that a user has many `CRM`s, and the `OneToOneField` means that the `CRM` has a single `client`. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I ended up solving it. I had run syncdb and migrate (via South) and thought that the databases were working as they should but apparently they weren't so I dropped the CRM table.

Comment: same issue, `sync db` solved it for me, but does anyone know why?!